# How to render a city in 3D with my geo json file

Tags: d3.js, geolocation, three.js, geojson, geo

i try lots of codes worked with  three.js, D3.js and d3-threeD.js they are works with different countries in europe but i cant draw my own city (Mashhad - Iran)
i need something exactly like this:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/render-geographic-information-3d-threejs-and-d3js

Comment: Maybe this example will help you. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html. If not, you are going to have to show your code and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: thanks for youre example i asked this question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111166/i-want-to-render-geojson-with-three-js-and-d3-js we have a problem with TRANSLATE_0 : -360,
TRANSLATE_1 : 10040,
SCALE : 60000 we dont know how to calculate these params.

Comment: i gave geojson data i dont have path that because i have problem with youre example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ViziCities](https://github.com/robhawkes/vizicities)** might be what you're looking for: it  uses, among other things, three.js + GeoJSON to render 3D cities.

[image: Screenshot from the Github repository]

However I did a quick test locating your city in Google Maps to get the coordinates (36.2862071, 59.6200235) and make a quick test, but either I have the wrong coordinates, either the data provider from the default example doesn't have data for your city.